# Erro ao compilar Class Library + Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, compilação

Criei um projeto Class Library no Visual Studio 2013 Express usando o framework 4.5, mas ao dar um Build na Class Library acontece o seguinte erro :

> ------ Build started: Project: AdComFramework, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>     C:\Users\COMERCIAL.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\dnx.exe --appbase "C:\Users\COMERCIAL\Desktop\Projetos\Sistema AdCom\AdComFramework" "C:\Users\COMERCIAL.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin\lib\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager.dll" pack "C:\Users\COMERCIAL\Desktop\Projetos\Sistema AdCom\AdComFramework" --configuration Release --out "..\artifacts\bin\AdComFramework"
>     System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager' ou uma de suas dependências. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
>     Nome do arquivo: 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'
>        em System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>        em System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>        em System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>        em System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
>        em Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
>        em Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
>        em Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
>        em Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
>     AVI: o log de ligações de assembly está desativado.
>     Para ativar o log de  falhas de assembly, defina o valor do Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
>     Observação: há alguma penalidade para o desempenho associada ao log de falha de ligação de assembly.
>     Para desativar esse recurso, remova o valor do Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo erro, ele esta tentando usar o novo asp.net. Vejo que você esta usando o Visual Studio 2013 Express, a Microsft libero o 2015 uma versão free (community) https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx